# Suggestion for Books on Visualization and Natural Language Processing

Tags: data-visualization, natural-language

[image: http://nirvacana.com/thoughts/becoming-a-data-scientist/]

This graphic is due to Swami Chandrasekaran.

I just started learning skills for data science recently. I have basics in R, Python, Statistics, Machine Learning. Now, I want to learn the Visualization and NLP part. What books should I begin with, that covers most of what listed above?

Practical books are preferred, because I want to try immediately with data available on internet (e.g. data.gov). Nevertheless, suggestions for theoretical books are welcomed too.

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.amazon.com/ggplot2-Elegant-Graphics-Data-Analysis/dp/0387981403](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387981403) 
[http://www.amazon.com/Interactive-Data-Visualization-Scott-Murray/dp/1449339735/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449339735)
and for the general philosophy of data visualisation and analysis of plots, let's go with immortal classic: [http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Display-Quantitative-Information/dp/0961392142/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961392142)
For NLP I'm curious about people's suggestions myself. In the meantime, I'm working my way through teaching materials from Dr Collins' website: http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/ and they  look great :)

Comment: How do the second book related to R, Python or any other statistical software? Could you please explain it? I'm confused.

Comment: Murray's book teaches you D3.js and JSON which are important tools especially for data scientists working in Web domain; the Roadmap you cite mentions those as well - in essence, it expands your toolbox. Tufte's work is actually older than R, Python and most modern statistical packages, it's more about the general approach and methods rather than using particular software.

Answer (score 1):

For a nice applied introduction to DV, I really like Nathan Yau's [two books](http://flowingdata.com/book/): *Visualize This* and *Data Points*. The first one is a bit more task oriented. For instance, it surveys the programming tools that are commonly used, including tutorials. There's some material on interactive graphics as well. The second is a bit more conceptual, though still with lots of examples.